# Old sci-fi book set in post apocalyptic future with shock-absorbing hovercrafts

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

It was a stand alone sci fi book, and in it there were helmets..? that stored information. I'm pretty sure it was set in a post apocalyptic future and it had old technology like hover crafts. There are are group of “heroes” looking for a lost helmet and they’re racing to find it before another group of people.

I know it’s a weird tidbit but the hovercrafts had shock-absorbing foam and the hovercrafts had trouble crossing rough terrain.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you've already [asked elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/sciencefiction/comments/af46lr/im_trying_to_remember_a_specific_sci_fi_book/) and excluded “Helm” by Steven Gould.